# Javascript using for...in loop with objects

Tags: javascript-objects, for-in-loop

Is anyone can help me to found this output.
Sample output:

```
['milk', 'bread', 'potato']
[20, 15, 10]
```

Here is the code.

```
var itemsToBuy = {
    milk: {
        quantity : 5,
        price: 20
    },
    bread: {
        quantity : 2,
        price: 15
    },
    potato: {
        quantity : 3,
        price: 10
    }
}
```

I have found for first array using `Object.keys(itemsToBuy)` but not able to found for second array.

Answer (score 1):

User `Object.values` and `map` for second array

```js
var itemsToBuy = {
  milk: { quantity: 5, price: 20 },
  bread: { quantity: 2, price: 15 },
  potato: { quantity: 3, price: 10 },
};

const out1 = Object.keys(itemsToBuy);
const out2 = Object.values(itemsToBuy).map(({ price }) => price);

console.log(out1, out2);

// Using for..in loop

const out3 = [];

for(const key in itemsToBuy) {
  out3.push(itemsToBuy[key].price)
}

console.log(out3)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object.values(itemsToBuy).map(item => item.price)` should do the trick